# Develop a distributed Full-Text search Index (AKA Inverted index)

Tags: full-text-search, scalability, sharding, full-text-indexing, inverted-index

I know how to develop a simple inverted index on a single machine. In short it is a standard hash table  kept in-memory where:
 - key - a word
 - value - a List of word locations
As an example, the code is here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Inverted_Index#Java

**Question:**

Now I'm trying to make it distributed among n nodes and in turn:

1. Make this index horizontally scalable
2. Apply automatic sharding to this index.

I'm interested especially in automatic sharding. Any ideas or links are welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sharding by it self is quite a complex task which is not completely solved in the modern DBs. Typical problems in distributed DBs are a [CAP theorem](http://blog.beany.co.kr/archives/275), and some other low-level and quite challenging tasks like rebalancing your cluster data after adding a new blank node or after naturally-occured imbalance in the data.

The best data distribution implemented in a DB I've seen was in Cassandra. However full text search is not yet implemented in Cassandra, so you might consider building your distributed index upon it.

Some other already implemented options are [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and [SolrCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/How+SolrCloud+Works). In the example given one important detail is missing which is a word-stemming. With word stemming you basically search for any form of a word like "sing", "sings", "singer". [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) and two previous solutions have it implemented for the majority of the languages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've found a comparison of Cassandra and some other DBs and came across consistent hashing algorithm again at: http://www.quora.com/How-would-you-compare-and-contrast-MySQL-sharding-vs-Cassandra-vs-MongoDB Actually, previously I researched this algorithm which is described in my blog: http://ivoroshilin.com/2013/07/15/distributed-caching-under-consistent-hashing/ and think this algorithm can be applied to inverted index too. I guess keys of inverted index can be passed into Consistent hash data structure.

Comment: Correction: I want to hear also other approaches and pitfalls if I combining inverted index with consistent hashing

Comment: In the simplest form NoSQL DB with hash-based keys can be considered as a huge HashMap. So yes, you can simply pass your inverted index keys to the DB.